# Simple regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm new to regular expressions and tried to use the following concept:

```
(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

in this way:

```
import re

print re.match("(?(\w),+)", "a,,,,,").groups()
```

Got the following error :

```
error: 'bad character in group name'.
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out what's wrong about this expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should have been a simple example... could you give me an example what an id or name is?

Comment: It baffles me that you call it a "simple regular expression" when you have no idea how to use it. :)

Comment: It looks like you really want `\w,+` - you don't need a condition here...

Comment: Either way, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html , under **Conditionals**. It seems only .Net supports sub pattern conditionals, but some flavor also support `(?(?=\w)yes|no)`. It is somewhat outdated, but Python isn't listed as one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write a valid `id` or `name`.

I found the [definition](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`
>
> Will try to match with `yes-pattern` if the group with given `id` or `name`
>   exists, and with `no-pattern` if it
>   doesn’t. `no-pattern` is optional and
>   can be omitted. For example,
>   `(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>)` is a
>   poor email matching pattern, which
>   will match with '`<user@host.com>`' as
>   well as '`user@host.com`', but not with
>   '`<user@host.com`'.
>
> New in version 2.4.

In your case, you haven't provided the `id/name` of a group to search for. Are you sure that this is the feature you want?

Comment: Thanks, I thought the condition must also be an expression.

Comment: @ahojnnes: It's an `id` or `name`.